# defining variables for semaphore

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, semaphore

I have two questions:

1. the variables sum and counter in this code are defined as 
   **long long** ? I changed them into int , but it did not give me similar counting, like the codes without threads and semaphore! Why does count get semi-random values (even by setting it to zero in for loop again)?
2. How can I reach to 1+2+3.../10 ? I mean, what is the impact of type of 
   variables (those not related to semaphore, process and threads. i.e `pid_t`)?

Thank you in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
sem_t s1;
char running = 1;
long long counter = 0;
void * process() {
  while (running) {
    sem_wait(&s1);
    counter++;
    sem_post(&s1);
  }
  printf("Thread: exit\n");
  pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main() {
  int i;
  long long sum = 0;
  pthread_t thread_Id;
  sem_init(&s1, 0, 1);
  if (pthread_create(&thread_Id, NULL, process, NULL)) {
    printf("ERROR in pthread_create()\n");
    exit(-1);
  }

  for (i=0 ; i < 10 ; i++) {
    sleep(1);
    sem_wait(&s1);
    printf("counter = %lld\n", counter);
    sum += counter;
    counter = 0;
    sem_post(&s1);
  }

  sem_wait(&s1);
  running = 0;
  sem_post(&s1);
  pthread_join(thread_Id, NULL);
  printf("Average Instructions = %lld \n", sum/10);

  return 0;

}
```

Comment: You get semi-random value because program spend different time on execution (time between `running` set to 1 and then set to 0).

Answer (score 1):

> 1.the variables sum and counter in this code are defined as long long ? I changed them into int , but it did not give me similar counting,

Not sure what you mean by that. Changing `int` to `long long` for both `counter` and `sum` (and adjusting the `%` formatting specifier accordingly to e.g. `%d`) should not (meaningfully) change the meaning of the program. In x86_64 Linux, you will be using a 32-bit counter, instead of a 64-bit one.

> like the codes without threads and semaphore!

Well, we would need to see the other program, but see below.

> why count get semi-random values (even by setting it to zero in for loop again)?

Because there are two concurrent threads running. One is incrementing the counter and the other is resetting it every second. There is no way to predict how many times the other thread will be able to increment the counter. It will depend on the load of the system (between runs in the same machine) and on the system itself (between machines, i.e. how fast it is).

Typically, the only kind of system where the counter value could be "predicted" would be one with a non-OOO, fixed frequency processor with a deterministic scheduler/operating system, etc. A common desktop is not such a machine -- the complete opposite, in fact!

I would suggest reading up on operating systems, their scheduler, timeslicing, etc.

Comment: first of all thnx a lot.
if I want to explain more :
I mean change the defining of long Long count, to int count and the same for sum. 
after this change and also changing %lld to %d there is no change in the result (that you explained).
I made a mistake in my question: int counter , gave me similar semi-random result, sorry for that. I thought that the changing the type of counter, can change the result. 
@Acorn